# Size of the glycan chain in a glycosylated protein

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, database

I would like to know where I can find the (experimental/estimated) distribution of glycan sizes attached to proteins.

Comment: Uniprot [includes](http://www.uniprot.org/help/carbohyd) glycosylation info if known...

Comment: @MattDMo I was expecting something more "digested". Anyway, thank you I will check uniprot.